# Writing an if-else inside a HAML in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

Sorry if it is a beginner question, just my first day of using HAML and still not used to it.

So I have this in my HAML:

```
%td= number_to_percentage(thera.group_dispense_rate, precision: 0)
```

I want to update it to say if `thera.group_dispense_rate` was `nil` then instead use `thera.provider_dispense_rate`

So I just needed some help to update this HAML logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the double pipe (OR operator)*:

```
number_to_percentage(thera.group_dispense_rate || thera.provider_dispense_rate, precision: 0)
```

The double-pipe (OR operator)* in action:

```
1.9.3p448 :090 > nil || "Bonjour Cartman"
# => "Bonjour Cartman"
```

**Attention**: the double-pipe *works for* `nil` and `false`, but *does not work* for empty stuff (array, string, hash) and not for zeros (Integer).

---

The longer version, for HAML:

```
%td
  - if thera.group_dispense_rate.present?
    = number_to_percentage(thera.group_dispense_rate, precision: 0)
  - else
    = number_to_percentage(thera.provider_dispence_rate, precision: 0)
```

**(OR operator) = boolean OR, thanks to @meagar*

Comment: shorter version you posted on first line also worked for me. Thanks. Do I need to switch to longer version you posted now?

Comment: No no, the second is here to respond to your precise question "*needed some help to update this HAML logic*", with the second option you could add more validations like `.present?` AND `> 0` for instance. The first one works only for `nil` & `false`, not for empty/zeros

Comment: Instead of "double pipe", you should really just call it by it's actual name, "boolean OR". It's the "or operator". Not the "double pipe".